# How can we unpivot 2 different set of columns in to 2 columns in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have a source table as below

[image]

now my requirement is how can i unpivot columns Introduction and Rapport in to one and Introduction Notes and Rapport Notes in to other column. my target table should be as below

[image]

I have used cross apply but i am unable to display the column Question in the target table which has 1 set of column names(introduction and Rapport).

can anyone have idea how this can be achieved in sql

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT A.Id
     , B.Question
     , B.ResponseRating
     , B.Response
FROM (VALUES -- Dummy Data
    (1, 3, 1, 'Completed', 'Assigned')
  , (2, 5, 5, 'Assigned', 'Completed')
  , (3, 4, 2, 'Completed', 'InProgress')
  , (4, 3, 3, 'InProgress', 'Changed')
) A (Id, Introduction, Rapport, IntroductionNotes, RapportNotes)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES -- Unpivot 
    ('Introduction', A.Introduction, A.IntroductionNotes)
  , ('Rapport', A.Rapport, A.RapportNotes)
) B (Question, ResponseRating, Response)
ORDER BY A.Id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look onto the `UNPIVOT` function.

You'll find a nice guide at http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Stairway+Series/125504/ (with an example of a nested UNPIVOT) and another one at http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3000/use-sql-servers-unpivot-operator-to-help-normalize-output/